# Terra::interpolate problem with quantiles prediction (R)

Tags: interpolation, prediction, quantile, quantile-regression

I have a problem. I am trying to generate prediction rasters for n tiles containing covariates of the following quantiles: 0.05,0.5,0.95. (I used [ranger](/questions/tagged/ranger) to create the model)

Below is the part of the script

"tile" are the raster stacks (the study area was divided into n stacks to avoid problems with memory) containing all covariates
"y" is the nth tile
"Boruta_covs" is the list of covariates that were chosen in the Boruta feature selection

```
quant <- c(0.05,0.5,0.95)
for (y in seq_along(tile)) {
  gc()
  # load tiles
  tl <- rast(tile[y])
  # crop the selected covariates with the nth tile y
  covs_fin <- crop(covs[[Boruta_covs]], tl)
  
  # function to extract the predicted values from from the ranger model
  pfun <- \(...) { predict(...)$predictions |> tl() }
  
  # predict quantiles
  terra::interpolate(covs_fin, 
                     model = model_qrf$finalModel, 
                     fun=pfun, 
                     na.rm=TRUE, 
                     type = "quantiles", 
                     quantiles = quant,
                     filename = paste0("my directory",
                                       soilatt,"_tile50d_", y, ".tif"), 
                     overwrite = TRUE)
  
  print(paste("tile", y, "of", length(tile)))
}
```

Mean and standard deviation were calculated without any problems.

> Eroor is a s following: ERROR: [writeValues] too many values for writing: 1751952 > 8588

I was trying to apply

```
type = "quantiles", 
quantiles =  c(0.05,0.5,0.95)`or predict individual
```

```
type = "quantiles", 
quantiles =  c(0.05)
```

But the same problem appeared

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please edit your question and provide a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example? That is, use a small dataset that ships with R or that you generate with code. See the R help files and Q/A on this site for examples. You can also simplify your example by removing the loop over tiles (this should not be necessary with your actual data either, but that is another matter).